# What should we do with a bad request?

Tags: php, security

In php, when you process GET/POST requests, you must check them etc. What if a parameter is missing or bad? If it's supposed to be some kind of hack, what should you do then? Just `die();` with "dontHackMe"?

Comment: Send back Bad Request HTTP status code.

Comment: How you respond to invalid data depends on the application, but generally it's better to provide a useful error message with a description of what went wrong.

Comment: I might didn't get you well , but javascript is a great tool for checking whether inserted data is valid or not

Comment: @itamar: No, it's not.  JavaScript is a great tool for providing a smoother user experience for data validation, but it is _not_ a great tool for actually sanitizing the data before it's used server-side.  Anybody can disable JavaScript.  The server-side code should _always_ perform data validation *for the exact reason specified in the question* (hacking attempts).

Answer (score 3):

No, don't just `die()` with "dontHackMe".  I see two outcomes for that:

1. If the user isn't malicious and it was a bug or an honest problem, you've offered the user no recourse for help.
2. That's actually a quite amateurish response and may even provoke an actual attacker to look for more security holes.

HTTP defines [a list of status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for responses.  Simply choose the correct one and respond with that code, along with a default response page of some kind.

For example, if the request is malformed or incorrect in some way, then the 400 (Bad Request) response code is the way to go.  The actual page in the response should indicate that it was a bad request and perhaps even offer an option for the user to seek help if they need it (such as a link to a help section on the site or a link to a contact form).

The reason for this response structure is two-fold:

1. By offering a helpful page, you create a human-readable form of output which people can see and appreciate, making your application that much more user-friendly.
2. By returning the correct status codes in your responses (all of your responses, not just rejected potential hacking attempts), you create a machine-readable interface that automated clients can use to more effectively interact with your application.  (A 400 response, for example, tells a non-malicious automated client that it shouldn't even bother making that request again... The request was received and processed and was found to be bad.)

**Edit:** To clarify... This is for responding to genuinely *bad* requests.  If the data being submitted in a form is simply incorrect (doesn't meet business rules, uses a letter where a number was intended, etc.) then [Michael Hampton offers a perfectly sound suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11428234/328193).  Essentially the server would "play dumb" and just re-display the form.

Don't give a potential attacker *any* more information than they already have.  (Keeping in mind that a bad error message is more information than they already have.)  The application would simply be saying, "Hmm... You tried to submit this form, but it's wrong.  Here, try again."

Answer (score 1):

Don't send an HTTP 4xx response unless something was wrong with the HTTP headers themselves.

If you receive invalid input from the client, redisplay the form with the invalid fields highlighted as being invalid.